# How to correlate MP4 excerpt to frame(s) of video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I have an MP4 file, and a 16kb excerpt from the file.  I would like to know what frame(s) the excerpt matches.  I can find the offset of the excerpt, but I believe MP4 encoding is variable-length (so I can't just say "this excerpt is from frame #(offset/framesize)")  That also means that my excerpt might not be on a valid frame boundary, so I can't just rename it to "excerpt.mp4" and play it.

What's a good way to figure out what frames correspond to the excerpt?

Comment: Are the excerpts stream copied segments (just re-muxed) or re-encoded?

Comment: No, it's just a raw range of bytes from the original MP4 file -- completely disconnected from MPEG frames or coding stream.  (The excerpt is actually at a 16kb boundary from the file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
ffprobe -show_entries frame=pkt_pos,pkt_size -select_streams v -of csv=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 in.mp4
```

Its output will be

```
48|33720
54534|76
53159|974
54920|381
34070|19089
68405|520
67315|740
69279|397
55627|11356
84445|534
83571|536
85314|979
```

where the first column is the starting byte offset of a frame and the 2nd column is the size. Frame `n` appears on line # `n`. You can use whatever shell tools..etc to check, for which line, your discovered offset value is between `position` and `position+size`. The position series may not be monotonic, so simply checking the first column isn't reliable.

Comment: That looks perfect...Synaptic on Debian-8 doesn't know about `ffprobe`, so I'm building ffmpeg-3.3.2 from source now.  I expect I'll accept this answer in a few minutes.  Thanks very much!